# Bash and IFS: string split to an array with specific separator based on a complete word-term

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, split

With the following code:

```
string="[Git status]^functionGitStatus"
IFS='^' read -r -a array <<< "$string"
echo "${array[@]}"
echo "size: '${#array[@]}'"
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
   echo "'$e'"
done
```

It works as expected and shows:

```
[Git status] functionGitStatus
size: '2'
'[Git status]'
'functionGitStatus'
```

I did do a research and for example at

- [How to split a string into an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash)

is possible use `,`  (command with empty space)

If I try to accomplish the same approach:

```
string="[Git status]^ functionGitStatus"
IFS='^ ' read -r -a array <<< "$string"
echo "${array[@]}"
echo "size: '${#array[@]}'"
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
   echo "'$e'"
done
```

I got:

```
[Git status] functionGitStatus
size: '3'
'[Git'
'status]'
'functionGitStatus'
```

sadly ***not*** as expected (even when only exists one ocurrence with `^` )

I want to know if is possible to use a complete word-term as separator for example:

```
string="[Git status]-fn:-functionGitStatus"
IFS='-fn:-' read -r -a array <<< "$string"
echo "${array[@]}"
echo "size: '${#array[@]}'"
for e in "${array[@]}"; do
   echo "'$e'"
done
```

But it shows:

```
[Git status]      u ctio GitStatus
size: '9'
'[Git status]'
''
''
''
''
''
'u'
'ctio'
'GitStatus'
```

Seems is not possible or perhaps there is a special flag to interpret how *complete word-term*. If is not possible what other function would help in this scenario?

Comment: `IFS` is treated as a *set* of characters that can be used as delimiters, not a single multi-character delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash parameter expansion and `mapfile`:

```sh
$ string='[Git status]-fn:-functionGitStatus'
$ mapfile -t array <<< "${string//-fn:-/$'\n'}"
$ echo "${array[@]}"
[Git status] functionGitStatus
$ echo "size: '${#array[@]}'"
2
$ for e in "${array[@]}"; do echo "'$e'"; done
'[Git status]'
'functionGitStatus'
```

Explanation: `"${string//-fn:-/$'\n'}"` is a bash parameter expansion with substitution: all (because `//` instead of `/`) `-fn:-` substrings in `string` are replaced by `$'\n'`, that is, a newline (the `$'...'` syntax is documented in the *QUOTING* section of bash manual). `<<<` is the here-string redirection operator. It "feeds" the `mapfile`command with the result of the parameter expansion with substitution. `mapfile -t array` (also documented in the bash manual) stores its input in the bash array named `array`, one line per cell, removing the trailing newline character (`-t` option).

Comment: If you can add a brief explanation of the `mapfile -t array <<< "${string//-fn:-/$'\n'}"` line would be nice. Thank You

Comment: I added some explanation but nothing replaces the bash manual (`man bash`) that you can search with patterns. For instance, if you type `man bash`, and then slash-`<<<` you'll find the here-string section. Same with `mapfile`.