# Unable to assign variable in Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, makefile

In `Makefile`, when I am assigning `bash` variable to `Makefile` file, it is not working, empty string is assigned. In below code, variable `LINE` and variable `y` are empty.

```
SHELL = bash
target:
        while read -r CURRENT_LINE; do \
                echo "$$CURRENT_LINE" ; \ ##WORKING FINE, display line by line
                LINE=$(shell echo "$$CURRENT_LINE") ; \ ##NOT WORKING
                echo "line:-$(LINE)" ; \ ##empty
                LINE=$$(CURRENT_LINE) ; \ ##NOT WORKING
                echo "line:-$(LINE)" ; \ ##empty
                y=$(subst :, ,$$CURRENT_LINE) ; \ ##NOT WORKING
                echo "y:- $(y)"; \  ##empty

        done < sample_file.txt ;
```

Comment: `$(shell ...)` executes in make, not the shell, so it can't access shell variables.

Comment: `$$(CURRENT_LINE)` should be `$$CURRENT_LINE`

Comment: @Barmar what would be correct syntax as I want to split the `CURRENT_LINE` by delimiter or space? How to access the value of `CURRENT_LINE`

Comment: Why not read directly into multiple variables? `while read -r var1 var2 var3 ...`

Comment: If you want an array, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash

Comment: As I am reading line by line from a file, so `CURRENT_LINE` is the current line that I am processing at a time. Now I want to split this line by delimiter.

Comment: `while read -r CURRENT_LINE; do IFS=', ' read -r -a array <<< "$$CURRENT_LINE" ; echo "${array[0]}" ;  done <receipe.txt ; ` This is also not working

Comment: You could just use `while read -r -a array; do ...`

Comment: @piyush-balwani `array` is a shell variable, so `echo "$${array[0]}`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @William. `while read -r -a array; do echo "$${array[1]}" done <receipe.txt ` is working.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be:

```
        while read -r CURRENT_LINE; do \
                LINE="$${CURRENT_LINE}" ;
                echo "LINE:$${LINE}"; \
        done
```

You need to distinguish between make variables and bash variables, and understand that make expands make variables *before* passing strings to the shell.

```
                echo "$$CURRENT_LINE" ; \ ##WORKING FINE, display line by line
                LINE=$(shell echo "$$CURRENT_LINE") ; \ ##NOT WORKING
                echo "line:-$(LINE)" ; \ ##empty
```

This has two errors: first, you're running $(shell ...), which starts a new shell when make is parsing the recipe...  (notice that this is *before* the recipe runs, and therefore before `CURRENT_LINE` is set), so in this shell instance, `$CURRENT_LINE` will expand to empty.   The second issue is that you're doing an echo of `$(LINE)`, which is also expanded at make parse time to *make*'s value of its `LINE` variable.   You would need to use `$$LINE`, which make would expand to `$LINE` before passing to the shell, and then the shell would be able to expand to its value of `$LINE`.

For the next part:

```
                LINE=$$(CURRENT_LINE) ; \ ##NOT WORKING
                echo "line:-$(LINE)" ; \ ##empty
```

First line should be `LINE=$$CURRENT_LINE` or `LINE=$${CURRENT_LINE}`.  Bash treats items in `$(...)` as commands, not variables.   This also has a second error that the echo line echo's `$(LINE)` is again a *make* variable, which is empty.

```
                y=$(subst :, ,$$CURRENT_LINE) ; \ ##NOT WORKING
                echo "y:- $(y)"; \  ##empty
```

So again this is an order thing -- `$(subst ...)` is expanded at make parse time (before the recipe is actually passed to shell).   What it's doing is it's substituting on the string `$CURRENT_LINE`, not the expanded version of this.   Also, you're printing the make version of `$(y)` again.