# How to extract number from string in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to extract number from string in shell
string is "1.69.0"

```
string="1.69.0"
```

I am looking for those numbers in 3 different variables
like num1=1, num2=69, num3=0.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here, sounds very much like version-number management

Answer (score 5):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash):

```
str="1.69.0"
IFS=. read -r -a num <<<"$str"
echo "${num[0]}"
echo "${num[1]}"
echo "${num[2]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, it is possible to store your version numbers in a list in the following way:

```
version="2.3.5-0041"
version_list=( ${version//[-.]/${IFS:0:1}} )
echo "Major release: ${version_list[0]}"
echo "Minor release: ${version_list[1]}"
echo "Patch level  : ${version_list[2]}"
echo "Build number : ${version_list[3]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if [[ $string =~ ^([[:digit:]]+)[.]([[:digit:]]+)[.]([[:digit:]])$ ]]
then
  first_num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  second_num=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  third_num=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
else
  echo Invalid content: "'$string'" 1>&2
fi
```

which also would verify that `string` indeed has the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$ eval "m=($(echo $string | tr '.' ' '))"
$ echo ${m[*]}
1 69 0
```

This assumes all strings are similar '.' separators only

Comment: easier would be to say `m=( ${string//./ } )`