# Shell Script: Split file with multiple lines on delimiter

Tags: bash, shell

I tryed a lot to to split a big file on a delimiter with more than one character (e.g. "2024-01-18"). The goal is to receive a array which can be used for further processing. I searched a lot, but unfortunatley I have no success. IFS for example is only useable with one char.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk` to be honest. I couldn't give you the exact syntax off the top of my head but you can definitely use regexes as field separators in awk. Otherwise maybe some kind of lisp tools could do it like [txr](https://www.nongnu.org/txr/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of part of my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225463/10971581.

Declare bash function:

```
mysplit(){
    local -n a=$1
    readarray -td '' a < <(
        gawk '
            BEGIN {
                RS = FS = "\0"
                ORS = ""
                gsub(/[\\.^$(){}\[\]|*+?]/,"\\\\&",d)
            }
            {
                gsub(d,"\0")
                print
            }
        ' d="$2" < "$3"
    )
}
```

Then:

```
mysplit arrayvar '2024-01-18' big_file
```

will store content of `big_file` split on string `2024-01-18` into bash array variable `arrayvar`

---

Size of file that can be processed is limited by the RAM available to gawk to process the longest null-delimited "line" in `big_file`.

bash variables cannot contain nuls so are used as the delimiter to `readarray` and for gawk.

Requires bash version >= 4.4.

Comment: Thanks for the information. When I execute the script mysplit arrayvar '2024-01-18' "$bigfile" it prints out the complete file. After the last entry I always get " : File name too long"

Comment: Does `"$bigfile"` expand to the name of your file?

Comment: It is a variable with the content of a file

Comment: your question asked to split a file, not a string. you can use my other answer to split a string