# Shell Script: How to trim spaces from a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to trim whitespace from bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)

I have searched and attempted a number of solutions but nothing seems to work for me...

I have a shell variable which is causing issues due to leading and trailing spaces. how can we get rid of all the spaces in a single line using shell script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can think of two options:

```
variable="  gfgergj lkjgrg  "
echo $variable | sed 's,^ *,,; s, *$,,'
```

or else

```
nospaces=${variable## } # remove leading spaces
nospaces=${variable%% } # remove trailing spaces
```

Comment: `nospaces=${variable// }` actually removes leading and trailing spaces  in my Bash

Comment: nospaces=${variable// } removes all spaces

Comment: nospaces=${variable// } removes all spaces

Comment: The second option removes at most one space. This [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486606/4377192) is rather long, only applies to bash, but is quite efficient and can also take care of tabs, newlines etc.

Answer (score 1):

there are so many ways to achieve that, awk oneliner:

```
kent$  echo "    foo  -  -  -  bar   "|awk '{sub(/^ */,"",$0);sub(/ *$/,"",$0)}1'
foo  -  -  -  bar
```