# Bash watch text file

Tags: file, bash, text, watch

I'm trying to make a small script which watches the latest log file in a folder and grabs the chat from the log, which i'll then display in a tmux panel but for some reason it can't find the file while it does exist

```
FILENAME=server_logs/$(ls -t1 server_logs | head -n 1)
watch -n3 'grep "\] " '$FILENAME' | tail -n15'
```

When i run the file it gives me this grep: server_logs/server_log_09_18_12.txt : No such file or directory

But if i use  `watch -n3 'grep "\] " server_logs/server_log_09_18_12.txt | tail -n15'` it does work.
So my question is why can't it find the file?

Comment: How are you running the script? If you're running it from cron for example, the start part his perhaps not what you thought.

Comment: I'm using "bash watch.sh" to run it, through SSH.

Comment: While I'd normally just use `tail -f ... | grep ...` for that, your command looks just fine. Is that your full script?

Comment: Does it run correctly in the script when you specify the full path to `server_logs/*`?

Comment: Two ideas: simplify the quoting a bit (`watch "cat '$FILENAME' | grep '\] ' | tail -n15"`) and use full paths (`$(readlink -f $(ls -t1 ... | head ))`). There is nothing really wrong with your code though.

Comment: @ShawnChin it is the entire code yeah, i've also tried specifying the whole path. I'll try your ideas gvalkov.

Comment: Also do check the if you have the right file access permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it didn't work, $FILENAME had some spaces at the end which caused the file not found error, so i used this:

```
FILENAME="${FILENAME#"${FILENAME%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace characters
FILENAME="${FILENAME%"${FILENAME##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace characters
```

Which i found at [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable).

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

> watch -n3 'grep "] " '$FILENAME' | tail -n15'

has two sets of ' quote signs.
You want to escape the inner ' signs.