# Bash : extracting part of a string

Tags: bash

Say I have the string "Memory Used: 19.54M"
How would I extract the 19.54 from it?
The 19.54 will change frequently so i need to store it in a variable and compare it with the value on the next iteration.

I imagine I need some combination of grep and regex, but I never really understood regex..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace from bash variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You probably want to *extract* it rather than *remove* it. You can use the Parameter Expansion to extract the value:

```
var="Memory Used: 19.54M"
var=${var#*: }            # Remove everything up to a colon and space
var=${var%M}              # Remove the M at the end
```

Note that bash can only compare integers, it has no floating point arithmetics support.

Comment: Extract does better explain what I want to do. How then would I change the third line to remove the "." and all that follows it?

Comment: `${var%.*}` removes a dot and anything following it at the end of the string.

Comment: may i ask what does # and * here means?

Comment: @once: As written in the comments, `#` means "remove from the left", and `*` is just a wildcard that matches everything.

Comment: Same effect could be archived with `${var//[A-Z,a-z,:]}`

Answer (score 52):

**Other possible solutions:**

With `grep`:

```
var="Memory Used: 19.54M"
var=`echo "$var" | grep -o "[0-9.]\+"`
```

With `sed`:

```
var="Memory Used: 19.54M"
var=`echo "$var" | sed 's/.*\ \([0-9\.]\+\).*/\1/g'`
```

With `cut`:

```
var="Memory Used: 19.54M"
var=`echo "$var" | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d 'M' -f 1`
```

With `awk`:

```
var="Memory Used: 19.54M"
var=`echo "$var" | awk -F'[M ]' '{print $4}'`
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use bash regex support with the `=~` operator, as follows:

```
var="Memory Used: 19.54M"
if [[ $var =~ Memory\ Used:\ (.+)M ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

This will print `19.54`

Answer (score 1):

```
> echo "Memory Used: 19.54M" | perl -pe 's/\d+\.\d+//g'
Memory Used: M
```