# Delete part of string Bash

Tags: linux, string, bash

I read [Bash : extracting part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671406/bash-removing-part-of-a-string).

How could I achieve this but for all matches inside a string:

```
x=something
echo ${x ome}
        ^
     what to put here to get "sthing"
```

Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the first answer is not right. All matches are to be removed. Therefore, the answer is:

```
echo ${x//ome/}
```

(See the manual.)

Answer (score 0):

It was too simple:

```
${x/ome/}
```

Another question that occurs to me now, is how could I put regular expressions inside the slashes but this is good for now.

Comment: You cannot. You can use shell patterns, though; see the Parameter Expansion section of the `bash` man page, scrolling down to `${parameter/pattern/string}`.