# How to remove space from string?

Tags: bash, shell

In ubuntu bash script how to remove space from one variable

string will be

```
   3918912k
```

Want to remove all blank space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable

Comment: Dupe trims, here goal is to remove all spaces.

Comment: trimming everything, at start, at the end and all in the midle:  echo '   aaa  bb            c'|xargs -L1 echo     it is all. of course you can change -L1 into -n1 , then all strings will be converted into separate lines.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try doing this in a shell:

```
var="  3918912k"
echo ${var//[[:blank:]]/}
```

That uses [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) (it's a non [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) feature)

`[[:blank:]]` is a POSIX regex class (remove spaces, tabs...), see http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: Substitution inside parameter expansion isn't POSIX. It will work in Bash (and maybe other shells I don't know), but not in Dash for example.

Comment: This one works also: 
str="${str// /}"

Answer (score 183):

The tools `sed` or `tr` will do this for you by swapping the whitespace for nothing

`sed 's/ //g'`

`tr -d ' '`

Example:

```
$ echo "   3918912k " | sed 's/ //g'
3918912k
```

Comment: Indeed, the currently accepted answer is not POSIX. For portable scripts, this answer is better.

Comment: How can I use it to save the result in a variable? Does it only work in `echo`? I'm having some trouble. Is it supposed to work like: `RESULT="$STR" | set "s/ //g"` ?

Comment: @cbdeveloper you could do this:
`RESULT=$(sed "s/ //g" <<< $STR)`

Comment: Does not work for strip newlines but only for blank spaces on a one line

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using bash, the fastest way would be:

```
shopt -s extglob # Allow extended globbing
var=" lakdjsf   lkadsjf "
echo "${var//+([[:space:]])/}"
```

It's fastest because it uses built-in functions instead of firing up extra processes.

However, if you want to do it in a POSIX-compliant way, use `sed`:

```
var=" lakdjsf   lkadsjf "
echo "$var" | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g'
```

Comment: In a non-interactive shell (i.e. a script), you need to `shopt -s extglob` for the first one.

Comment: @glennjackman Good catch.  See my updates.

Answer (score 6):

A funny way to remove all spaces from a variable is to use printf:

```
$ myvar='a cool variable    with   lots of   spaces in it'
$ printf -v myvar '%s' $myvar
$ echo "$myvar"
acoolvariablewithlotsofspacesinit
```

It turns out it's slightly more efficient than `myvar="${myvar// /}"`, but not safe regarding globs (`*`) that can appear in the string. So **don't use it in production code.**

If you really really want to use this method and are really worried about the globbing thing (and you really should), you can use `set -f` (which disables globbing altogether):

```
$ ls
file1  file2
$ myvar='  a cool variable with spaces  and  oh! no! there is  a  glob  *  in it'
$ echo "$myvar"
  a cool variable with spaces  and  oh! no! there is  a  glob  *  in it
$ printf '%s' $myvar ; echo
acoolvariablewithspacesandoh!no!thereisaglobfile1file2init
$ # See the trouble? Let's fix it with set -f:
$ set -f
$ printf '%s' $myvar ; echo
acoolvariablewithspacesandoh!no!thereisaglob*init
$ # Since we like globbing, we unset the f option:
$ set +f
```

I posted this answer just because it's funny, not to use it in practice.

Comment: However in this case, the quotes are explicitly missing in order to remove the leading whitespace. So glob chars are in play.

Comment: Condensed to a safe one line: `myvar="$( set -f; printf "%s" $myvar )"; echo "[$myvar]"`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `echo` to remove blank spaces, either at the beginning or at the end of the string, but also repeating spaces inside the string.

```
$ myVar="    kokor    iiij     ook      "
$ echo "$myVar"
    kokor    iiij     ook      
$ myVar=`echo $myVar`
$
$ # myVar is not set to "kokor iiij ook"
$ echo "$myVar"
kokor iiij ook
```

Comment: This is not reliable : if `myVar` contains special characters like `*`, the shell will expand it with the files of the current directory.

Comment: As #bash on freenode always says... use more quotes. `echo "$myvar"` prevents expansion of globs, etc.

Comment: @bobpaul, it prevents expansion of globs, etc, but also includes the leading and trailing whitespaces Mickaël intended to get rid of :(