# String concatenation without spaces to make a file path

Tags: linux, concatenation, csh

I am currently debugging some prewritten csh scripts to make them executable. I am running into some issues when it comes to combining two strings to create a complete file path.

I need to combine the file path:

```bash
rdir = ../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_
```

with a dynamic file name:

```bash
mcs = 68320
nm = ${mcs}.txt (for example)
```

When trying to combine these two strings the output has large amounts of white space between the variables that I am unsure how to get rid of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I've tried:

1. `file = ${rdir}${nm}`

`output = ../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_                   68320.txt`

2. `file = echo ${rdir}${nm}`

`output = ../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_                   68320.txt`

3. `file = "${rdir}${nm}"`

`output = ../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_                   68320.txt`

2. `` file = echo `${rdir}${nm}` ``

`output = ../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_                   68320.txt`

What I was expecting:
`output = ../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_68320.txt`

Comment: After positing this I realized stack did not keep the spaces I put in the example outputs. There is about 3 tabs worth of space between the combined strings. Hope this clarifies any confusion about what I'm asking.

Comment: You can (and should) use [markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make those whitespace characters visible.

Comment: You need to show _real_ shell (bash?) syntax, not some kind of pseudo code! `file = ${rdir}${nm}` is invalid syntax (well, not really; but it does not assign a variable, but calls the program `file` with at least one parameter). You cannot use `echo` the way you've shown to assign variables. Please [edit] the question to include _real_ assignments (copy them from your script).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your problem. As is, we can't really help you. The only thing I can say is that your example of variable affectation aren't bash anyway (`rdir = ../something` isn't a bash command. Or, more accurately, it is: it is command `rdir` called with argument `=` and argument `../something`, which is obviously not what you want. And, unless you do have a `rdir` command, that should just fail). EDIT: crossed message with @knittl. But at least, you see that there is some unconcerted unanimity about that... :D

Comment: @pmf thanks for the tips. I just joined stack and was unsure about how to use all the features so I appreciate the help.

Comment: The title states "Bash", the tags say [tag:bash], but the content contains "csh". Which shell is it?

Comment: @knittl The `csh` tag was also there but has been removed by others.

Comment: `csh` has a confusing mix of assigment syntaxs, depending if you want a "local" shell variable `set locvar = "value with spaces"` or an environment variable (visible to child processes) : `setenv envvar "other value with spaces"`. (local variable is my take on this, and may offend purists! Warning!) (-;! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing as the formatting is wrong, but you should do this

```
bash% rdir='../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_'
bash% mcs='68320'; nm="${mcs}.txt"
bash% file="$rdir/$nm"
bash% echo "'$file'"
'../picks/rec_files/REC_FILE_/68320.txt'
```

and you can verify there's no extra spaces.

Comment: @Diego Torres Milano Thank you for the comment! After lots of trial and error I found a couple trailing spaces in some random spots in my line. Thank you for drawing my attention to that possible issue <3

Answer (score -1):

A sure way regardless of the shell variant you are using would be to pipe the concaneted variables and sanitize them from the spaces with stream editor, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662036/21898431).

The expression would give `echo "${rdir}${nm}"  | sed 's/ //g'`