# Extracting part of a string to a variable in bash

Tags: string, bash, sed, find, extract

noob here, sorry if a repost. I am extracting a string from a file, and end up with a line, something like:

```
abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde
```

Let's say it's in a variable named testString
the length of the values between the colons is not constant, but I want to save the number, as a string is fine, to a variable, between the 2nd and 3rd colons. so in this case I'd end up with my new variable, let's call it extractedNum, being 67890 . I assume I have to use sed but have never used it and trying to get my head around it...
Can anyone help? Cheers

On a side-note, I am using find to extract the entire line from a string, by searching for the 1st string of characters, in this case the abcdefg part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace from bash variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's another pure bash way. Works fine when your input is reasonably consistent and you don't need much flexibility in which section you pick out.

```
extractedNum="${testString#*:}"     # Remove through first :
extractedNum="${extractedNum#*:}"   # Remove through second :
extractedNum="${extractedNum%%:*}"  # Remove from next : to end of string
```

You could also filter the file while reading it, in a while loop for example:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r col line ; do
    # col has the column you wanted, line has the whole line
    # # #
done < <(sed -e 's/\([^:]*:\)\{2\}\([^:]*\).*/\2 &/' "yourfile")
```

The sed command is picking out the 2nd column and delimiting that value from the entire line with a space. If you don't need the entire line, just remove the space+& from the replacement and drop the line variable from the read. You can pick any column by changing the number in the \{2\} bit. (Put the command in double quotes if you want to use a variable there.)

Comment: Old post, but because yr answer was accepted, could you complete it with an ever so short explanation of the 'done < <(sed ...)' syntax ? (the sed part is clear, i am wondering about the two right to left redirect-like <. Tx.

Comment: How would I extract `("123" "vbm-container")` from this?

echo $raw_containers_string
[
  {
    "name": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "vbm-container"
  }
]

Answer (score 20):

Pure Bash using an array:

```
testString="abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde"
IFS=':'
array=( $testString )
echo "value = ${array[2]}"
```

The output:

```
value = 67890
```

Comment: Very elegant (+1), but (unfortunately) only valid for array supporting linux shells such as bash!

Comment: pretty sure thats what the OP asked for... bash

Answer (score 7):

You can use `cut` for this kind of stuff. Here you go:

```
VAR=$(echo abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde |cut -d":" -f3); echo $VAR
```

For the fun of it, this is how I would (not) do this with `sed`, but I'm sure there's easier ways. I guess that'd be a question of my own to future readers ;)

```
echo abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde |sed -e "s/[^:]*:[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1/"
```

Comment: Thanks for the lightning response, I'll give it a go!

Comment: And on another note, how would I then use that later to put this number back into a new string, replacing what's in between the second and third colons?

Comment: I suppose `awt` is better suited the more complext it goes. With sed, you could do `echo abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde | sed -e "s/\([^:]*:[^:]*:\)[^:]*\(:.*\)/\1WHATEVER\2/"`

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you: the key part is `awk -F: '$0=$3'`

```
NewVar=$(getTheLineSomehow...|awk -F: '$0=$3')
```

example:

```
kent$  newVar=$(echo "abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde"|awk -F: '$0=$3')

kent$  echo $newVar 
67890
```

if your text was stored in var `testString`, you could:

```
kent$  echo $testString                                                                                                                                                     
abcdefg:12345:67890:abcde:12345:abcde
kent$  newVar=$(awk -F: '$0=$3' <<<"$testString")
kent$  echo $newVar                                                                                                                                                         
67890
```