# Bug echo-ing multiple numerical values separated by commas

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have a weird bug, basically I have set up a function to run remote commands via SSH on a box and get the lan MAC address and some other info. I want to write this info into a csv file.

When I run `BOXLANMAC=$(remote_command "ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | cut -d' ' -f11")` I can echo $BOXLANMAC and get the expected output.

However, when I run `echo $BOXLANMAC,$BOXLANMAC` I get `,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` where I expect to see `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`. I have tried many permutations of the echo command, using quotes and escape characters for the comma, but not had any success. I'm sure this is really simple and I should have been able to figure it out, but google seems to just get me results about splitting strings on commas.

Comment: Strange.  I reproduced what your doing on a Linux box (albeit locally, not remotely), and I got the expected output when I did `echo $boxlanman,$boxlanmac`.  I'm wondering if when you do it remotely, perhaps there is some weird whitespace character (like a tab, cr, or lf) coming back at the beginning or end of the output from the command, which is getting assigned to $boxlanmac, and is affecting the output when the $boxlanmac variable is echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As das.cyklone and I mentioned above, you might want to see if the remote command is returning whitespaces which are affecting the output of the echo command.  Perhaps using `tr` to remove any whitespaces from the $boxlanmac variable will solve the problem.  See [How to trim whitespace from a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable) for ways to do this.

Comment: thanks, this fixed it, I did `MAC=$(echo $MAC | tr -d '\r') and that works :)

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to work fine during testing. I can offer two suggestions:

1) Use awk instead of cut for whitespace. It's more reliable and easier to test.

2) If echo isn't working, try printf. It gives you more control with statements.

```
~-> BOXLANMAC=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | awk '{ print $5 }')
~-> echo ${BOXLANMAC}
78:2B:CB:88:E5:AR
~-> echo ${BOXLANMAC},${BOXLANMAC}
78:2B:CB:88:E5:AR,78:2B:CB:88:E5:AR
~-> printf "%s,%s\n" ${BOXLANMAC} ${BOXLANMAC}
78:2B:CB:88:E5:AR,78:2B:CB:88:E5:AR
~->
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but printf didn't work, it must be something related to the remote command

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: echo ${BOXLANMAC},${BOXLANMAC} ?