# Bash variable substitution

Tags: bash

I have a variable containing four numbers separated by a space, such as for instance:

```
a="12.3 423.4 11.0033 14.02"
```

But sometimes, I have a trailing whitespace:

```
a="12.3 423.4 11.0033 14.02 "
```

I want to replace the spaces with " & ", and for that, I do:

```
echo ${a// / & }
```

Which gives me:

```
12.3 & 423.4 & 11.0033 & 14.02
```

or if I have a trailing whitespace:

```
12.3 & 423.4 & 11.0033 & 14.02 &
```

My problem is that I don't know if I'll have a space at the end of my string and I don't want that extra "&" in any case. What would be the most elegant way to avoid this extra character? Is there a way to say "replace if a space and the next character a digit"?

**Edit:** I knew I could use sed, but since there is a mechanism of variable substitution in bash, I would like to know how could I use it to do what I want. I don't know how to write "not end of line" or "is a digit" in the bash substitution.

Comment: And do you want to keep that trailing space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace from bash variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)

Comment: @danadam I want the result to be "12.3 & 423.4 & 11.0033 & 14.02" with or without the trailing space.

Comment: @el_tenedor it is not a duplicate but it might be a possible solution. However, I am looking for the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will remove trailing space if there is any:

```
a=${a% }
```

Then you can do your replace:

```
a=${a// / & }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use `${${a% }// / & }` unless someone comes with a better idea. I'll pick the best answer later. *Edit:* hum, bash says bad substitution while it's fine for zsh... I need to do it in 2 steps as you did.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed and capture the match.

```
$ echo 12.3 423.4 11.0033 14.02 | sed 's/ [0-9]/ \&&/g'
12.3 & 423.4 & 11.0033 & 14.02
```

So with the `/ [0-9]/` you're only replacing where there is a space followed by a number.

If you didn't want to use sed you could check that the next character isn't EOL.

```
${a// [^$]/ & }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it directly with bash variable substitution (without sed)?

Comment: I don't believe so, as you can only substitute with bash substitution. You cannot use regex and I don't think you can capture the match. Sed is the way forward! :)

Comment: So apparently, you can use regex!

Comment: Sorry but your solution doesn't work actually: you are removing the characters that match [^$].

Comment: Hmm... It worked when i tested it. Have you definitely got the space before the `[^$]`. (i.e. `/ [^$]/`)?

Comment: On the example, I have: `12.3 & 23.4 & 1.0033 & 4.02` (your solution using sed works however).

Comment: @lifesaspanner `bash` parameter substitution uses glob patterns, not regular expressions.

Comment: @chepner Aaah. That would be I can't do a negative lookahead!

Comment: @Maxime You're quite right, it does replace the character. It seems the only options are removing the trailing space, or use sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob            # enable extended globbing patterns
b=${a/%+([[:blank:]])/}     # remove trailing whitespace
b=${b/#+([[:blank:]])/}     # remove leading whitespace
b=${b//+([[:blank:]])/ & }  # globally replace whitespace by " & "
echo ">$a<"
echo ">$b<"
```

```
>12.3 423.4 11.0033 14.02 <
>12.3 & 423.4 & 11.0033 & 14.02<
```

references:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a contrived approach, but FWIW. If you are ok with multiple consecutive spaces being replaced with a single `&`, you could use bash `read` and `printf` built-ins to  split the string into a array (assuming default whitespace `IFS` for the split) and then join back using a temporary `IFS` of `&`, see below.

```
a="12.3 423.4 11.0033 14.02 "
read -r -a x <<< "${a}"
IFS='&' eval 'printf -v a "%s" "${x[*]}"'
echo $a
12.3&423.4&11.0033&14.02
```

Comment: I like your definition of "elegant" :). Definitively not mine but +1 for the creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just do

```
a=`echo "12.3 423.4 11.0033 14.02 " | sed 's/ *$//'`
echo ${a// / & }
```

That way you're removing the trailing whitespaces.