# Bash If Statement - Giving up hope

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I have tried and tried to solve this and with my limited knowledge of BASH i cannot, I have searched but cannot find anything relating to my issue.

```
COMMAND_WAIT=$(curl --data "SERIAL_NUMBER="$SERIALNUMBER"" h**p://SERVER/device_check_in.php)

echo $COMMAND

if [ "$COMMAND_WAIT" == "REBOOT" ]; then

echo "Reboot Scheduled"

else

echo "Nothing Found"

fi
```

I have included an echo command of "COMMAND_WAIT" and this displays "REBOOT" as expected but the if statement will just not work?

Comment: `echo $COMMAND` or `echo $COMMAND_WAIT`?

Comment: Sorry echo $COMMAND_WAIT

Comment: Is this truly `bash`, or some shell that does not allow `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: Simplify: get rid of the curl and write `COMMAND_WAIT=REBOOT` and see if the problem persists.  Probably you have extra whitespace in the variable.  Try `echo ::$COMMAND_WAIT::` and look for whitespace.

Comment: Hiya, That solved it getting rid of the curl proved there is not quite "REBOOT" being returned, Turns out its " REBOOT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try echoing

```
echo ">>$COMMAND_WAIT<<"
```

and see if you have any padding. That might be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [[]] instead of [] since [ is a builtin (a command) while [[ is a keyword (see bash manual for more details).

```
  if [[ "$VAR" == "VALUE" ]]
  then
     echo "true";
  else
     echo "false";
  fi
```

If it's trailling whitespaces, there's many way to skin that cat like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)