# Find Strings in File - Package Feed - bash script

Tags: bash, repository

I have following package repository format

```
Package: enigma2-plugin-extensions-airplayer
Version: 0.3.9
Section: extra
Architecture: all
Maintainer: hellmaster1024 and DonDavici <hellmaster1024 and DonDavici@code.google.com/p/airplayer/>
MD5Sum: b0c862e749846521ea11eeae77ddf905
Size: 166268
Filename: enigma2-plugin-extensions-airplayer_0.3.9_mips32el.ipk
Source: ftp://code.google.com/p/airplayer//hellmaster1024 and DonDavici/airplayer-0.3.9.tar.gz
Description: Enigma2 Plugin AirPlayer by hellmaster1024 and DonDavici
OE: airplayer-0.3.9
HomePage: code.google.com/p/airplayer/
Priority: optional


Package: enigma2-plugin-extensions-atmolightd
Version: 0.7-pre22
Section: extra
Architecture: all
Maintainer: mamba0815 <mamba0815@gmx.li>
MD5Sum: af17593ec8ad4a00c1fa843ccb17be6f
Size: 851522
Filename: enigma2-plugin-extensions-atmolightd_0.7-pre22_all.ipk
Source: www.noip.com
Description: Sedulight/Atmolight/amBXlight/Karatelight for Enigma2
OE: 1.6
HomePage: http://www.i-have-a-dreambox.com/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=136415
Priority: optional
```

Now I need a bash script which finds in a Loop the "Package Name" example "enigma2-plugin-extensions-atmolightd" and the "Filename" example enigma2-plugin-extensions-atmolightd_0.7-pre22_all.ipk

I started with following script

```
for i in `cat Packages.txt |grep Filename|cut -b 11-`; do
 wget "http://sources.dreamboxupdate.com/opendreambox/1.5/dm7025/feed/$i";
done
```

I can download all the packages - but I miss the Package Name.
Want to create a folder with the Package Name and then store all versions of the packages into this folder.

For sure this can be solved with Regex?
But I am not good at this,...

Greet`s erich

## My final solution

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "Downloading all Packages from the feed"

rootPath="/tmp/Openwrt/Trunk"
#echo $rootPath
mkdir -p $rootPath

wget -O "$rootPath/Packages" http://enigma2.world-of-satellite.com/feeds/3.0/et9x00/3rdparty/Packages

while read -r p f; do
   mkdir -p "$rootPath/$p" 2>/dev/null
   wget -nc -P "$rootPath/$p" "http://enigma2.world-of-satellite.com/feeds/3.0/et9x00/3rdparty/$f"
done < <(awk -F ' *: *' '$1=="Package"{p=$2;next} $1=="Filename"{print p, $2}' "$rootPath/Packages")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
while read -r p f; do
   mkdir -p "$p" 2>/dev/null
   wget "http://sources.dreamboxupdate.com/opendreambox/1.5/dm7025/feed/$f"
done < <(awk -F ' *: *' '$1=="Package"{p=$2;next} $1=="Filename"{print p, $2}' Packages.txt)
```

**Explanation:**

- awk command used input field separator as `:` and searches input file for `Package` and `Filename` lines. If found both values are printed in same line with a space delimiter.
- `while read` command reads both values in variable `p and f`. These variables are used for further processing.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer!  

I only had to edit the code a little bit, because the packages were not saved in the created fodlers.  

With a -P as parameter for the destination path and a -nc for skipping downloaded I am very happy!  

Amazing what a few lines of code can manage if you know what you are doing ;)

Comment: Nice would be if you could explain in words what the while loop with the awk command is doing exactly - I would like to understand it ;)

Comment: I will add explanation to my answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea might be like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
#example_script.sh
package="";
filename="";
while read line
do
  echo "$line" | grep "Package"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    package=`echo "$line" | grep "Package" | cut -f 2 -d ":"  | tr -d ' '`
    mkdir -p "$package"
  fi
  echo "$line" | grep "Filename"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    filename=`echo "$line" | grep "Filename" | cut -f 2 -d ":" | tr -d ' '`
    cd "$package"
    wget "YOUR_BASE_URL_GOES_HERE/$filename"
    cd ..
  fi
done < $1
```

Then call it.

```
./example_script.sh filename.txt
```

*[Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929453/bash-scripting-read-file-line-by-line)
*http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html
*[How to trim whitespace from a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)
*http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir
*http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution - it was working on the first try ;)