# Printing array elements without white space using printf

Tags: arrays, bash, printf, echo

I can print my array elemets using echo in a loop, but the output format is really bad . there I tried injecting tab but there is just a lot of spaces between the elements ssince each element length is different. I have no idea how to use printf ? I tried , but it just not working properly. is there a way to format my printf or echo so I have equal number of spaces between each element?  This is driving me mad.

```
while [[ $counter -lt $nai ]];
do
#echo ${slist[$counter]} $'\t' ${sstate[$counter]} $'\t' $'\t' ${scached[$counter]}
printf ${slist[$counter]} $'\t' ${sstate[$counter]} $'\t' $'\t' ${scached[$counter]}
counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
done
```

IN short I just want to print my elements in a format with equal number of spaces between the elements like this

```
  abc  cdf  efg
```

What i'm getting is

```
  abc       cdf            efg
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you : [How to trim whitespace from bash variable ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)

Comment: @Martin `"your print statement" | tr -s ' ' ' '` Check if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print elements with N spaces between them, you can use printf:

```
a="foo"
b="somestring"
c="bar"

# Print each argument with three spaces between them
printf "%s   " "$a" "$b" "$c"
# Print a line feed afterwards
printf "\n"
```

This results in:

```
foo   somestring   bar
otherdata   foo   bar
```

You can also use the format `%-12s` to pad each element to 12 character:

```
# Pad each field to 12 characters
printf "%-12s" "$a" "$b" "$c"
printf "\n"
```

Resulting in:

```
foo         somestring  bar         
otherdata   foo         bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a format string with printf

```
printf "%s  %s  %s\n" ${slist[$counter]} ${sstate[$counter]} ${scached[$counter]}
```

If the fields don't have whitespace, use `column -t`:

```
{
echo my dog has fleas
echo some random words here
} | column -t
```

```
my    dog     has    fleas
some  random  words  here
```

Or, in your case:  `while ...; do ...; done | column -t`

Comment: Thanks its much better .. there is equal spacing .. but since the elements are not of equal length still they are not aligned properly. Is there a way to align them properly?

Comment: Answer updated. It would have been helpful to show more than a single line of sample input.