# removing linebreak from a line read from a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file containing some lines. I wanted to store each line to a variable , but the line must be chomped (the way its done in perl - chomp($Line) ) in shell script.

The code containing the functionality of opening a file and reading the lines is

```
p_file() {

File=$1
count=0

while read LINE
do
      chomped_line=$LINE    **#How to delete the linebreaks** 
      echo $chomped_line

done < $File

}
```

How to delete the linebreaks and store the string in the variable(chomped_line) as above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable

Answer (score 22):

Simply use

```
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r line
```

It would exclude leading and trailing spaces even carriage returns characters (`\r`) every line. No need to chomp it.

If you still want to include other spaces besides `\n` and/or `\r`, just don't specify the others:

```
while IFS=$'\r\n' read -r line
```

Another way if you don't like using IFS is just to trim out `\r`:

```
chomped_line=${line%$'\r'}
```

*****  `-r` prevents backslashes to escape any characters.

Comment: ${LINE%$'\r'} is the only thing that works for me. wsl2/ ubuntu.