# Remove the trailing spaces from command line passed param in bash

Tags: bash

I run a command:

```
script.sh ___bubu__
```

The content of the `script.sh` is:

```
echo $1
```

When executed I get

```
___bubu__
```

How can I remove the trailing spaces from command line passed arguments?
I copy some params from a file and when pasting into command line I get some spaces and I do not want to manually remove the space. I am planning to use $1 as a parameter in a script. For example I want to create a folder with $1

Comment: When you say trailing spaces, do you actually mean leading underscores ?

Comment: Those quotes shouldn't be present in the output. Can you please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you're asking?

Comment: Trailing spaces would be removed if you echo without putting quotes around `$1`.

Comment: Question for removing space is duplicated for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
..> more strip.sh 
#!/bin/bash

arg=$1
arg=${arg// /}
echo "unstripped: --$1--"
echo "stripped: --$arg--"

.03:163> ./strip.sh "  test "
unstripped: --  test --
stripped: --test--
```