# bash sed (or others) to substitute front anchored double space AND trailing non-printable character

Tags: regex, bash, sed, tr

I've lines of the following form

```
line="  this is a line with 2 leading spaces and a trailing control char^M"
```

I want to substitute both the 2 leading spaces and the trailing control char represented here by ^M with nothing.

```
echo "${line}" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' | tr -dc '[:print:]'
echo "${line}" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' | sed 's/[^[:print:]]//'
```

both works. I also tried with

```
echo "${line}" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*|[^[:print:]]//'
```

but this doesn't work.

Why doesn't this last expression work?
How can I accomplish this with a single call to sed and a single regex?
What is the preferred solution, for example in terms of efficiency? Is it better to avoid many subshells?
Are there better solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace from bash variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-bash-variable)

Comment: you are missing a colon in your expression(`:print`) + you need to escape the 'or' operator (`\|`)

Comment: @ndn I read that post before asking and I don't think it is a duplicate since this question was intended to find a way to perform multiple substitution with a single sed call

Comment: @JiriKremser I've corrected the "[:print]" typo, thanks. Sorry to everyone for this long delay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*|[^[:print]]//'
```

doesn't work because `|` matches itself literally. "Or" is spelled `\|` in sed. (And `[:print]` should be `[:print:]`).

But that's still not enough because by default sed only replaces the first occurrence; you need the `/g` flag to replace all occurrences:

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*\|[^[:print:]]//g'
```

---

But your original regex may have some unintended consequences: `[[:space:]]` matches newlines, so if the input is one or more complete lines, it will remove all blank lines, not just their contents. To prevent this, use `[[:blank:]]` instead:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*\|[^[:print:]]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This single sed should work:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//; s/[[:cntrl:]]*$//' <<< "$line"
this is a line with 2 leading spaces and a trailing control char
```