# How to remove leading whitespace from a string in Bash

Tags: bash

For example, I have a string, "     some string", and I want to put "some string" in another string variable. How do I do that?

My code:

```
function get_title() {
    t1=$(get_type "$1")
    t2="ACM Transactions"
    t3="ELSEVIER"
    t4="IEEE Transactions"
    t5="MIT Press"
    if [ "$t1"=="$t2" ];
        then
        title=$(less "$1" | head -1)
    elif [ "$t1"=="$t5" ];
    then
        title=$(less "$1" | head -3)
    fi
    echo "$title"
}
```

As you can see the $title can return unwanted whitespace in front of text in center aligned texts. I want to prevent that.

Comment: Specifically, take a look at the third code block of the [top-rated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3232433/2489497) ("How to remove leading whitespace only")

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't check at that question because I didn't want to trim whitespace completely. @CalebBrinkman

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A robust and straightforward approach is to use *sed* e.g.

```
$ sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' <<< "$var"
```

If you are willing to turn on extended globbing (*shopt -s extglob*), then the following will remove initial whitespace from $var:

```
 "${var##+([[:space:]])}"
```

Example:

```
var=$' \t abc \t ' echo "=${var##+([[:space:]])}="
=abc   =
```

Comment: You can also use a capture group in a regular expression to avoid starting a new process for `sed`: `[[ $var =~ [[:space:]]*(.*) ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`