# nmcli con up command seems to add a trailing period when giving it a connection name from a variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a bash script that places the gsm modem connection name in a variable:

```
name=$(nmcli -f NAME, TYPE c | grep gsm | grep -oP '.*(?=gsm)')
```

`echo $name` gives me `"Provider connection"`.

However, when I use $name to bring the interface up I get the following:

```
nmcli -t con up id "$name"
```

results in `"Error: Unknown connection: Provider connection   ."`.

I've tried using ${name} as well and to try and find where the period is coming from I used "($name)" which results in "Error: Unknown connection: (Provider connection   )."
Also tried writing the connection name to a file an then reading that into a variable but no luck there.

Anybody know where that trailing period/dot comes from?

Comment: When you wrote the variable to file, what was actually written in the file?

Comment: I believe there's no trailing dot (the dot in the error message is probably a full stop to end the sentence), but rather, trailing spaces.

Comment: Yup, this is why I want to see the file contents.

Comment: The variable written to file was "Provider connection"  without the dot.

Comment: Thanks for your effort - I tried the solution below which yields only the dot.
"Error: Unknown connection: ."

Comment: Please could you show in bash the output of `echo "$name"` Only the output as it comes exactly, add no quotations.

Comment: Now try `echo "$name..."`

Comment: Provider connection      ...

Comment: There's your white space trailing

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, I'll call it. I think this is a whitespace issue, not a trailing period.

In this case, you should preprocess the variable before using it:

```
name="$(echo -e "${name}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"

nmcli -t con up id "$name"
```

This will remove only trailing white space, without affecting the actual string.

[image]
I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable

Comment: Still get the following:
Error: Unknown connection: .

Comment: what if you run the command `nmcli -t con up id Provider connection`

Comment: Seems like a malformed command to begin with, but I have no experience with nmcli

Comment: That does work nmcli -t con up id "Provider connection"
...it's only a problem when I run nmcli with the variable

Comment: can you follow the same command steps in my screen shot - I want to see if there is a Bash or sed variance at play.

Comment: name="$(echo -e "${name}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')" 
This command takes me to the > prompt

Comment: Found a solution:
Whitespace was definitly the issue so I used your advice and piped my command output to sed.

name=$(nmcli -f NAME, TYPE c | grep gsm | grep -oP '.*(?=gsm)' | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"

Answer (score -1):

Whitespace removal solved this issue. Removed with sed.

name=$(nmcli -f NAME, TYPE c | grep gsm | grep -oP '.*(?=gsm)' | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"