# Bash: opening file which name in listed inside another file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file that contains a list of file names to be opened later.
After I load lines (file names) to variables, for a reason unknown to me I cannot open it as a file later.

Here is a simplified example of what i'm trying to do:

Main file's contents:

```
first_file.txt
second_file.txt
```

Bash commands:

```
read line < $main_file   # file with the list, received as an argument
echo $line               # to check that correct filename has been read
cat $line                # attempt to dump "first_file.txt" contents <- FAILS
cat first_file.txt       # read "first_file.txt" contents manually
```

Execution esult:

```
first_file.txt
: No such file or directory
*** this is 1st file's contents ***
*** ....
```

So, `cat first_file.txt` works, `$line` contains "first_file.txt", but `cat $line` fails...

I obviously misunderstand something here, suggestions are welcomed!

Edit: 
As requested, here is `cat -v $main_file`'s output:

```
first_file.txt^M
second_file.txt^M
third_file.txt^M
^M
^M
```

Comment: Are there "hidden" characters, like say `\r` at the end of the lines in the source file?  Then it would print right, but not work.  Can you edit the question with the output of `cat -v main_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^M` characters are carriage returns (a.k.a. `\r`) and are often part of a Windows line ending.  They don't show up when you `echo` them, but they are messing up your ability to open a file with the text having it at the end.

The best solution is to remove them from your "main file."  You could use the `dos2unix` tool if you have it, or you could use GNU sed like `sed -i -e 's/\s+$//g' $main_file` to edit it in place and remove the extra white space (which includes `^M`) from the end of each line.

Comment: You are correct. I stripped leading and trailing white-spaces from the variable using: `line="$(echo -e "${line}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"` command, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable). And now it works! Thanks!