# How to store the xargs portion of code that strips whitespace in bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, whitespace, xargs

I have a bash variable that has an extra space before the text and I can get rid of it by doing

```
echo "$myvar" | xargs
```

However, I want to store the variable that has the '| xargs' applied to it as another variable as opposed to echo so I can use it for something else.

Comment: `newvar="${myvar# *}"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable

Comment: that does not work

Comment: `read newvar <<< $myvar` without quotes will strip whitespaces. I suggest you show your code and data samples with existing input and desired output. I don't like using `xargs` without a command to run - not its intended use...