# md5sum - ignore trailing whitespace

Tags: checksum, md5sum

Say I have two files:

1.json

```
{"foo":"bar"}\n
```

2.json

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

when using checksum routines, is there a way to ignore the trailing whitespace?

maybe something like this:

```
md5sum < <(cat file | trim_somehow)
```

Comment: Trailing newlines (and only newlines) are removed by shell command substitution (if the data fits in shell memory): `printf %s "$(cat file)" | md5sum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` or `xargs`.

`xargs` is much simpler, but be careful with it. **I'm not sure if it is safe to use in this context**. Read the comments below this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12973694/4330274. (There are a lot of answers to your question in that post).

`md5sum < <(cat file | xargs)` will delete trailing/leading whitespaces ***(Also, as stated by dave_thompson_085 on the comments down below, it will compress each whiltespace sequence to one whitespace and it will remove quotation marks and backslashes)*** from the file before passing it to the md5sum utility.

*Note: `xargs` appends a new line to the end of the input.*

I recommend using `sed` for this purpose. It is much safer. Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232433/4330274

Comment: sure how about all beginning/trailing whitespace?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the question, I will edit the answer.

Comment: `xargs` with the default `echo` also compresses any embedded whitespace sequence to a single SP, which isn't usually a problem for JSON, and removes all quotes and many backslashes, which is.

Comment: what do you mean "with the default echo"?

Comment: @AlexanderMills He is referring to the `echo` utility. Try `echo "Alexander 's'  /   Mills" | xargs`. All the whitespace sequences will be replaced with one whitespace. The quotation marks and the backslash will be removed, which is really a problem in case you use it with JSON since JSON uses quotation marks in its syntax.