# bash script variables weird results when using cp

Tags: scripting, carriage-return, cp

If I use cp inside a bash script the copied file will have weird charachters around the destination filename.
The destination name comes from the results of an operation, it's put inside a variable, and echoing the variable shows normal output.

The objective is to name a file after a string.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    newname=`cat outputfile | grep 'hostname ' | sed 's/hostname //g'
    newecho=`echo $newname`
    echo $newecho
    cp outputfile "$newecho"
```

If I launch the script the echo looks ok

```
    $ ./rename.sh
    mo-swc-56001
```

However the file is named differently

```
    ~$ ls
    'mo-swc-56001'$'\r'
```

As you can see the file contains extra charachters which the echo does not show.

Edit: the newline of the file is like this

```
    # file outputfile
    outputfile: ASCII text, with CRLF, CR line terminators
```

I tried in every possible way to get rid of the ^M charachter but this is an example of the hundreds of attempts

```
    # cat outputfile | grep 'hostname ' | sed 's/hostname //g' | cat -v
    mo-swc-56001^M

    # cat outputfile | grep 'hostname ' | sed 's/hostname //g' | cat -v |  sed 's/\r//g' | cat -v
    mo-swc-56001^M
```

This newline will stay there. Any ideas?

Edit: crazy, the only way is to perform a dos2unix on the output...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim whitespace from a Bash variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/how-to-trim-whitespace-from-a-bash-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your outputfile has `\r` characters in it, so you could add logic there to remove them and give it a try then.

```
#!/bin/bash
##remove control M first from outputfile  by tr command.
tr -d '\r' < outputfile  > temp && mv temp outputfile
newname=$(sed 's/hostname //g' outputfile)
newecho=`echo $newname`
echo $newecho
cp outputfile "$newecho"
```

Comment: @James Biffi, Could you please do let me know if this helps you?

Comment: I added some details in the question, there's a newline charachter that I can't get rid of.

Comment: @JamesBiffi, please check my EDIT command and let me know if that helps you?

Answer (score 0):

The only way was to use dos2unix