# Trim multiline strings in bash

Tags: bash, trim, line-breaks

Given a variable or stdout of a command in bash containing multiple lines, how can I trim leading and trailing whitespace characters (including line breaks)?

Note: I want to use this in trimmed string comparison, i.e.

```sh
[[ "$(command1-that-produces-multiline-string)" == "$(command2-that-produces-multiline-string)" ]]
```

As one of the commands produces trailing newline(s) while the other does not, the comparison fails.

Comment: `$(...)` strips trailing newlines, though it does not strip leading newlines or any whitespace.

Comment: In a slightly similar case [How to trim whitespace from a bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758/) helped me to get it working.